# Running an lm model for each df separately

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run a different model for each df and store it all in the same df after nesting.

Code example:

```
mt<- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,am) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(formula = "Add separate model for each row in text like mpg~wt for one row, mpg~wt+hp for another etc.")

mt$formula[[1]] <- "mpg~wt"
mt$formula[[2]] <- "mpg~wt+drat"
mt$formula[[3]] <- "mpg~wt+qsec"
mt$formula[[4]] <- "mpg~wt+gear"
mt$formula[[5]] <- "mpg~wt"

mt<- mutate(model = ?)
```

Comment: the 6th row is not a formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `map2` to loop over the `list` column 'data' and the corresponding elements of 'formula', apply the `lm` and assign it back to a new column 'model'

```
library(purrr)
mt$model <- vector('list', nrow(mt))
mt$model[1:5] <- map2(mt$data[1:5], mt$formula[1:5], ~ lm(.y, data = .x))
mt
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   cyl, am [6]
#    cyl    am data              formula                                                                                  model
#  <dbl> <dbl> <list>            <chr>                                                                                    <lis>
#1     6     1 <tibble [3 × 9]>  mpg~wt                                                                                   <lm> 
#2     4     1 <tibble [8 × 9]>  mpg~wt+drat                                                                              <lm> 
#3     6     0 <tibble [4 × 9]>  mpg~wt+qsec                                                                              <lm> 
#4     8     0 <tibble [12 × 9]> mpg~wt+gear                                                                              <lm> 
#5     4     0 <tibble [3 × 9]>  mpg~wt                                                                                   <lm> 
#6     8     1 <tibble [2 × 9]>  Add separate model for each row in text like mpg~wt for one row, mpg~wt+hp for another … <NUL…
```

Comment: Thanks.I have a couple of more general questions. Why does the formula need to be a list? And is there a more elegant way than specifying row numbers of the df (e.g by conditions of the row) when adding the formula?

Comment: @Stat.Enthus In your case, it is a string and it doesn't need to be a `list`.  i.e. you can have a regular column.

Comment: Thanks. What about this as an edit option (Does not work but that's the sense of the code) `mt$cyl[6]$am[1]$model <- "mpg~wt"`

Comment: @Stat.Enthus. I didn't understand the code you showed and the input data.  `mt$cyl[6]$am[1]`. Here, 'cyl' is a different column and 'am' is different

Comment: I am saying instead of specifying just a rownum of 1, to make the code more readable, I am trying to allocate to model by specifying the cyl and the am and the inserting the model. Forgive me for the "pseudode"

Comment: @Stat.Enthus You meant to say that creating the list column can be made easier?  `mt$formula[1:5] <- c("mpg~wt", "mpg~wt+drat", ....)`

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to make my code more readeable for another person. The person reading the code needs to understand that in the case of cyl=6 and am=1 the model is x, etc.. This makes more sense in the statistical aspect

Comment: @Stat.Enthus If you need to get the group values, use `cur_group` or `cur_group_id` gives the keys and id